Proving the sequence of the fractional part of the root of a natural number diverges
The following question is from a homework assignment.
Prove, from the definition, i.e, for all $ L \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists $\varepsilon > 0 $ such that for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$ there is a number $n>N$ such that $| a_n - L | \geq \varepsilon$, that the sequence $a_n = \langle \sqrt{n} \rangle$ does not have a limit.
$\langle x \rangle$ is the fractional part of $x$, $\langle x \rangle = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$.
We were given a hint, to prove that
$\sqrt{k^2-1} > k- \frac{1}{2}$ for all $1<k \in \mathbb{N}$.
Now, I understand that, if such a limit existed, then $0 \leq L <1$,thus this is where I should focus, I am just not sure how to proceed, within this interval.
Any hints would be greatly appreciated

Fractional Part is denoted as $\displaystyle\left{\cdots\right}$

Yes, I saw that in different textbooks, however this is the notation they chose in our class... This is why I added the explanation.

You find
$$\lfloor y\rfloor = N-1$$
for a number $y$ satisfying
$$N-1<y< N.$$
$\sqrt{N^2-1}$ is such a number, because with the HINT you find
$$N-\frac{1}{2}<\sqrt{N^2-1}$$
and therefore
$$N-1< (N-1)+\frac{1}{2} = N-\frac{1}{2}<\sqrt{N^2-1}<\sqrt{N^2}=N$$
This means
$$N-1<\sqrt{N^2-1}<N$$
which yields
$$\lfloor \sqrt{N^2-1}\rfloor = N-1$$
and
$$a_{N^2-1}=\sqrt{N^2-1} -(N-1)$$
Again with the HINT you find
$$N-\frac{1}{2}<\sqrt{N^2-1}$$
and you find
$$(N-1)+\frac{1}{2}=N-\frac{1}{2}<\sqrt{N^2-1}$$
and
$$(N-1)+\frac{1}{2}<\sqrt{N^2-1}$$
and
$$\frac{1}{2}<\sqrt{N^2-1}-(N-1)$$
and
$$\frac{1}{2}<\sqrt{N^2-1}-(N-1)=a_{N^2-1}$$
and
$$\frac{1}{2}\le |a_{N^2-1}-0|$$

For $L=0$ pick $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ and $n=N^2-1$. With the details above, it holds
$$\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}\le|a_n-L|=a_{N^2-1}=\sqrt{N^2-1} -(N-1).$$
For $L\ne 0$ pick $\varepsilon=|L|$ and $n=N^2$. Then it holds
$$\varepsilon=|L|\le|a_n-L|=|a_{N^2}-L|=|L|,$$
since
$$\sqrt{N^2}=N,\  \lfloor \sqrt{N^2}\rfloor=N \ \Longrightarrow\  a_{N^2}=0.$$
EDIT: To cover $N=1$ in the case $L=0$, you can pick $n=(N+1)^2-1=3$.

Thank you! I understand your explanation regarding the case $L \ne 0$, however, I think I am missing something, because $x<y$ does not imply ${x} < {y}$... So I am not sure how to use the hint (the lower bound)

I edited the answer... Please explain more precisely what you do not understand...

Now I got it!
Thank you very much for the elaborate answer!

We have that $\{\sqrt{n^2}\}=\{n\}=0$, so $a_{n^2}=0$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Thus, if the limit exists, it must be $0$.
However, using the recommended bound we have $$n-\dfrac{1}{2}<\sqrt{n^2-1}<\sqrt{n^2}=n$$
for every $n\in\mathbb{N}, n>1$.
Thus, $\dfrac{1}{2}<\{\sqrt{n^2-1}\}$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}, n>1$. Taking $\epsilon=\dfrac{1}{2}$ finishes the proof.

(+1) Simple and nice!

By contradiction, suppose there exists a limit $L$.
One has $(\{\sqrt n\})_{n\in\Bbb N}\in [0,1)\Rightarrow L\in[0,1]$. By our assumption,for all $\epsilon\gt0$ there exists $N$ such that $n\gt N$ implies $|\{\sqrt n\}_n-L|\lt \epsilon$.
$(1)$ $\underline{L\ne0}$.- In this case we should have for all $n\gt N$ $$|\{\sqrt n\}_n|\lt \epsilon\hspace1.cm(1)$$
The relation $(1)$ is not possible for all $n\gt N$ because, for example, for $n=x^2-1$ ,  its fractional part is near to $1$.
$(2)$ $\underline{L\ne1}$.- In this case $\sqrt{n^2+1}$  for $n$ large enough has  a small fractional part so we can deny $|\{\sqrt n\}_n-1|\lt \epsilon$ (series expansion around infinity gives $\sqrt{n^2+1}=n+\dfrac{1}{2n}-\dfrac{1}{8n^3}+O\left(\left(\dfrac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)$).
$(3)$ $\underline{L\notin(0,1)}$.- In this case the relation $|\{\sqrt n\}_n-L|\lt \epsilon$ can be deny  similarly to the two first cases $(1)$ and $(2)$ according with the magnitude of $L$ in $(0,1)$  (the size of $\{\sqrt n\}$  always going from $0$ to $1$)

More is true:
$\{\sqrt{n}\}$
is dense in $(0, 1)$.
For $0 < c < 2$, let
$f_c(n)=\sqrt{n^2+cn}-n
=\{\sqrt{n^2+cn}\}$.
Then,
since (see (*) below)
$1+x/2-x^2/8
\lt \sqrt{1+x}
\lt 1+x/2$
for $0 < x < 1$,
$\begin{array}\\
f_c(n)
&=\sqrt{n^2+cn}-n\\
&=n(\sqrt{1+c/n}-1)\\
&\lt n(c/(2n)\\
&=c/2\\
\text{and}\\
f_c(n)
&=n(\sqrt{1+c/n}-1)\\
&\gt n(c/(2n)-c^2/(8n^2))\\
&= c/2-c^2/(8n))\\
\end{array}
$
so
$\lim_{n \to \infty}
\{\sqrt{n^2+cn}\}
=c/2
$
so
$\{\sqrt{n}\}$
is dense in $(0, 1)$.
(*)
$\begin{array}\\
1+x-(1+x/2-x^2/8)^2
&=x^3/8-x^4/64\\
&=(x^3/64)(8-x)\\
&\gt 0
\qquad \text{for } 0 < x < 8\\
\end{array}
$
